# sort by number/id within an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

is there a way to order these (alal SELECT * FROM this ORDERBY....) in javascript. So if I just wanted to append  new list elements to a DOM from an object, but wanted to control the order kind of thing.

```
var example = [
                {id:1, data: { val1: 'val1', val2: 'val2'}, orderById: 313},
                {id:2, data: { val1: 'val1', val2: 'val2'}, orderById: 312},
              ];

var buildString = '';
for ( var i = 0; i < example.length; i++ ) {
   // wondering if there is another approach so that i could control the order as I build the string
   buildString += "<li class='example-class'>" + example[i].data.val1 + "</li>";
}

$("#some-ul").html('').append(buildString);
```

so if there is a totally better approach to accomplish this idea I am interested in learning...

Comment: Your array objects are already sorted by id. Do you need to sort by another property?

Comment: Example for sorting: `example.sort(function(a, b){ return a.id - b.id; });` (sorry, not enough time for a full answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have a method called [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) which does exactly as you might expect. It sorts the array. By default, this is done simply by comparing the elements. However, here you are sorting an array of objects, which are normally unsortable. You therefore have to tell the script how to compare the items, like so:

```
example.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.id - b.id;
});
```

Your function will be called for each comparison the engine needs to make (varies based on sorting algorithm used interally, doesn't really matter to us). `a` and `b` are the elements currently being compared. The function must return:

- a negative number if `a` is to be considered less than `b`
- a positive number if `b` is to be considered greater than `b`
- zero if the items are to be considered equal.

In this case, I simplified the expression into `a.id - b.id`. That's because as per basic maths:

- if `a.id` is less than `b.id`, the result is negative
- if `a.id` is greater than `b.id`, the result is positive
- if they are equal, the result is zero

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You would use the library Sugar which could do exactly what you are looking for:

http://sugarjs.com/api

```
[{age:35,name:'ken'},{age:15,name:'bob'}].groupBy(function(n) {
  return n.age; 
});
```

`{"15":[{"age":15,"name":"bob"}],"35":[{"age":35,"name":"ken"}]}`

But as Niet point out, if the only thing you would do is just a basic sort then the native array sort would be fine, but if it is more SQL like functions you search for, then Sugarjs can be great help.

Else http://www.taffydb.com/ would also be a good choice, that would help you great!

Comment: Really? You need to get a whole new library just to perform a basic sort?

Comment: He asked the question by listing a SQL statement, I then thought the library would be useful, because he would properly do other cool things to.